# Servlet, Java, PostgreSQLにて「いいね機能」を実装するには？

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, servlet

いいねのリンクを押し、記事ごとのいいねの総数を表示するプログラムを作りたいが、jspを実行しても作動しない。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**test.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import = "model.Goods" %>
<% Goods goods = new Goods(); %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>テスト画面</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href ="/gotoFukuoka/GoodAdd?user_id=<%=rs.getString("user_id")%>?article_id=<%= 
rs.getString("article_id")%>>いいね</a><br>
<p>いいね数：<%= goods.getGoodCnt() %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Goods.java(JavaBeans)**

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Goods implements Serializable{

    private String article_id;
    private String user_id;
    private int goodCnt;

    public int getGoodCnt() {
        return goodCnt;
    }
    public void setGoodCnt(int goodCnt) {
        this.goodCnt = goodCnt;
    }
    
    public Goods() {}
    public Goods(String article_id, String user_id) {
        this.article_id =article_id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getArticle_id() {
        return article_id;
    }

    public void setArcticle_id(String article_id) {
        this.article_id = article_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }


}
```

**GoodAdd.java(Servlet)**

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.GetGoodLogic;
import model.GoodLogic;
import model.Goods;

/**
 * いいね追加のコントローラ
 */
@WebServlet("/GoodAdd")
public class GoodAdd extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // リクエストパラメータから検索条件の取得、（JSPからuser_id, article_idを取得）
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            String user_id = request.getParameter("user_id");
            String article_id = request.getParameter("article_id");

            //データをGoods()のコンストラクタに入れる

            Goods goods = new Goods(user_id, article_id);
            GoodLogic goodLogic = new GoodLogic();
            goodLogic.goodPlus(goods);

            request.setAttribute("goods", goods);

    }

}
```

**GoodLogic.java(model)**

```
package model;

import dao.GoodsDAO;

public class GoodLogic {

    public void goodPlus(Goods goods) {

        GoodsDAO dao = new GoodsDAO();
        dao.insert(goods);
    }
}
```

**GetGoodLogic.java(model)**

```
package model;

import dao.GoodsDAO;

public class GetGoodLogic {
    public Goods execute(Goods goods) {

        GoodsDAO dao = new GoodsDAO();
        Goods good = dao.select();
        return good;
    }
}
```

**GoodsDAO**

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import model.Goods;

/*
 * いいねに関するＤＡＯクラス
 */
public class GoodsDAO {

     private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Goods";
        private final String user = "postgres";
        private final String passWord = "test";

        /********************************************************************************
         * 「いいね」テーブルから記事IDを検索し、いいねを集計して検索結果を返します。
         ********************************************************************************/
        public ResultSet select(String article_id) {
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;


            try {
                 /* JDBCドライバの定義 */
                 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

                 /* PostgreSQLへの接続 */
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passWord);

                 /* SELECT文の準備 */
                 String sql = "select article_id, count(*) ";
                 sql += "from Goods ";
                 sql += "group by article_id ";
                 sql += "order by count(*) DESC; ";
                 st = con.prepareStatement(sql);


                 /* SELECT文の実行 */
                 rs = st.executeQuery();


            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("DBアクセス時にエラーが発生しました。");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                 /* PostgreSQLとの接続を切断 */
                if(rs != null) {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {}
                }

                if(st != null) {
                    try {
                        st.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {}
                }

                if(con != null) {
                    try {
                        con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {}
                }
            }

            return rs;
        }

        /********************************************************************************
         * 「いいね」テーブルにいいねを追加します
         ********************************************************************************/

        public int insert(Goods goods) {
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement st = null;
            int rs = 0;//更新件数

            try {
                 /* JDBCドライバの定義 */
                 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

                 /* PostgreSQLへの接続 */
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passWord);

                 /* INSERT文の準備 */
                 String sql = "";
                 sql = "INSERT INTO Goods(user_id, article_id) ";
                 sql += "VALUES(?, ?);";

                 st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                 st.setString(1, goods.getUser_id());
                 st.setString(2, goods.getArticle_id());

                 /* SELECT文の実行 */
                 rs = st.executeUpdate();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("DBアクセス時にエラーが発生しました。");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                /* PostgreSQLとの接続を切断 */
                if(st != null) {
                    try {
                        st.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {}
                }

                if(con != null) {
                    try {
                        con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {}
                }
            }


            return rs;
        }
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE Goods(
  user_id       VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
  article_id    SERIAL        NOT NULL,
  good          NUMERIC       DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (article_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

間違っているところは他にもあるかもしれませんが、少なくとも明らかに間違っているのは次の行ですね。

```
<a href ="/gotoFukuoka/GoodAdd?user_id=<%=rs.getString("user_id")%>?article_id=<%= 
rs.getString("article_id")%>>いいね</a><br>
```

二つ目のクエリーパラメーターが`?article_id=`となっているので、`request.getParameter("article_id")`はnullにはなるはず。なので`&article_id=`に変更する必要があります。